# How to send standard output (like echo) to S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to send the output of an 'echo' to an S3 file. Similar to how we can do something like echo 'Hello World' > file.txt, I'm doing

aws s3 cp s3://dirname/dirsubfolder/file.txt > echo 'Hello World'. However, I get Key "file.txt" does not exist. I know the file doesn't exist, but I want to copy the output as that file - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This [feature](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/903) was added in 2014, but I could not find it in the cli help docs.

```sh
echo "Hello World" | aws s3 cp - s3://example-bucket/hello.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pipe command output into the `aws s3 cp` command line tool, just like you can't pipe text like that into the standard `cp` command. Also, the command you are trying:

```
aws s3 cp s3://dirname/dirsubfolder/file.txt > echo 'Hello World'
```

is actually piping the output of `aws s3 cp` command into the `echo` command, which is the exact opposite of what you say you are trying to do.

You're going to need to script this in a couple steps like:

```
echo 'Hello World' > /tmp/file.txt
aws s3 cp /tmp/file.txt s3://dirname/dirsubfolder/file.txt
rm /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: S3 does not allow named pipes: "Skipping file /dev/fd/63. File is character special device, block special device, FIFO, or socket."  So you can't do process substitution such as `aws s3 cp <(echo "Hello World") s3://example-bucket/hello.txt`